# Angular: changing single route emits multiple 'NavigationEnd' events

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-router

I am using Angular 4, and this is my code in one of the component where I need to catch that route has changed and reload the page.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((value) => {
          if (value instanceof NavigationEnd) {
             console.log(value);
          }
        });
    }
```

My problem is that I get multiple 'NavigationEnd' events for one route. 
For some route console.log write even 6,7 values.

How that can happen ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume that by "reload page" you mean calling the `navigate` method of `this.router`. If thats the case, this is most likely related to the fact that you create a new observer of the router events every time that you create an instance of this component, but dont dispose the generated `subscription` in the `ngOnDestroy` cycle. To solve this, you could do the following:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';    

export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private _routerSub = Subscription.EMPTY;
   constructor(private router: Router){}

   ngOnInit(){
     this._routerSub = this.router.events
         .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
         .do(event => console.log(value)) // use do operator for log operations
         .subscribe((value) => {
          //do something with the value
         });
   }

   ngOnDestroy(){
     this._routerSub.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. That was my problem, I did not destroy unsubscribe event on  'ngOnDestroy'. I did not know that I should do that :)

Comment: This should not be necessary per Angular documentation. Router events are cold observables and do not need to be unsubscribed.

Comment: The `Router.events` observable being cold/hot has no relation to the necessity of unsubscribing from it. Where did you got this from?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#!#route-parameters .  but I see now that it is subscription to ActivatedRoute

Comment: I am destroying the subscriber on ngOnDestroy, but it creates a problem for me, it unsubscribes before it gets the instance of navigationend. please can anyone tell me what to do about this?